# Function only returns true for first element in array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that will return `true` if either 'purple' or 'magenta' elements are present in an array. However my code will only return `true` when either purple or magenta are the first item in the array:

```
function containsPurple(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === 'purple' || arr[i] === 'magenta') {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

So for example, `containsPurple(['black', 'magenta', 'yellow'])` returns `false`, however `containsPurple(['magenta', 'black', 'yellow'])` returns `true`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Move return false; outside the for loop

Answer (score 1):

Consider your condition:

```
if (arr[i] === 'purple' || arr[i] === 'magenta') {
  return true;
}
return false;
```

Let's assume that `arr[i] === 'orange'`. Does it match your if-condition? No. So it continues to the next line, which is `return false`. Once a function encounters a return statement, the function is completed and the return value is returned. Never will your loop go to the next iteration, because in the first iteration it will always encounter a `return` statement (it be either `return true` or `return false`).

To fix this you can move the `return false` outside of your loop. This way it will keep looping until any iteration matches the `if` condition. If not, it will exit the loop and continue to the `return false` and finish the function with the return value `false`.

```js
function containsPurple(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === 'purple' || arr[i] === 'magenta') {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log('black, yellow', containsPurple(['black', 'yellow']));
console.log('black, magenta, yellow', containsPurple(['black', 'magenta', 'yellow']));
console.log('magenta, black, yellow', containsPurple(['magenta', 'black', 'yellow']));
```

That being said, in your case you can simplify your code using [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
function containsPurple(arr) {
  return arr.some(element => element === 'purple' || element === 'magenta');
}

console.log('black, yellow', containsPurple(['black', 'yellow']));
console.log('black, magenta, yellow', containsPurple(['black', 'magenta', 'yellow']));
console.log('magenta, black, yellow', containsPurple(['magenta', 'black', 'yellow']));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function containsPurple(arr){
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] === 'purple' || arr[i] === 'magenta'){
            return true;
        }
       // you're returning false after checking only the first value
       // return false;
    }
    // return false once you checked the entire array
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code, how it differs, and why it solves their problem.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer Did that. I commented the line which was wrong with explanation

Comment: I would move it outside of the code block, easily skipped over. Just paste it as text above. Maybe explain why returning false ends the for-loop.